# In angular Nested ng-if is not supporting safari 9

Tags: angular

In angular Nested ng-if is not supporting safari 9. Can i use polyfills or some other to support it? Im looking for work around.Kindly some one help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: Using angular 4 with webpack

Comment: Angular is not AngularJS, it uses [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf), not `ng-if`

Comment: No browser has support for `ngIf`. So this question makes no sense in its current form. Please describe your actual problem

Comment: *ngif="condition"   this way my code goes by...

Comment: only for first time page load issue is reproducing, once i refresh the page again it works good. kindly guide me..